# How to spawn a golem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I started minecraft I always saw the golems, but I never knew how to spawn one. I searched through the spawn eggs about 1,000 times but never found the spawn egg for the golem. Then, giving up I searched on google and yes I know I should probably gone there first, but anyway here.
First you start with taking iron blocks and placing two up and then take two iron blocks and put them on the side of the top iron block, across from each other.

Then take a carved pumpkin, **NOT A Jack-O-Lantern**  and place it on the middle top block. (This does not work under water or with any other material I have tried)[image]

Comment: This seems more like a tutorial to teach others rather than a question asking for help. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so please be sure to format your questions *like a question*.

Comment: FYI: next time, just type `/summon minecraft:iron_golem` in the chat to save time. Chat can be opened by pressing T.

Comment: sry I just think it's easier to do some stuff like this, but don't worry  I will post a lot of questions.

Comment: also chat really doesn't work that great like you say on Nintendo Switch, at least not on mine, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6):

Essential part: the two blocks under "arms" of the golem must be empty - `minecraft:air`. Not tall grass (like in your case), snow, flowers, flowing water or anything else.

Also, the carved pumpkin must be placed last.

Comment: Hey, I just looked up a pick so people know what it's supposed to look like. (I've been told I'm bad at explaining stuff).

Answer (score 0):

[image: how to build an iron golem]

You have to place the 4 iron blocks and the carved pumpkin like in the picture above. Make sure there are no other blocks under and above his arms.

Please tell if it worked or not.
Have a great day!